# Free or Open Source Diagramming Component for WinForms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, graphics, diagramming

I need to be able to generate dependency diagrams programmatically. I'd like it to be able to generate a bunch of boxes with labels and connectors linking them, and ideally the component would position them automatically onto a design surface which could then be manually rearranged.

I'm using WinForms and C# 2.0 (VS2005).

EDIT: However, since it'll be an internal tool, I can probably use 3.5 SP1 and WPF if there any suggestions in that arena.

Must be free or open source.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) which is being distributed under CPL (i.e. free of charge). It is not exactly for .NET/WinForms but can be useful anyway. The library's main purpose is to visualize graphs (and dependency diagram is effectively a [directional] graph). You can use it to either get an image (graph layout) or an array of points (coordinates for you items).

Comment: Interesting. I guess I could write some code which transforms my own input to whatever format GraphViz takes and run it against that. Worth investigating - might be better than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Thanks for this, it's working well although the diagrams are large and are going to be hard to format for printing. It would be good if I could do a little manual adjustment - do you know of a way? I wonder if I render as SVG can I import into Visio?

Comment: Unfortunately I have not tried any of this (was not in need) so I cannot help you here.

Answer (score 12):

Too late for the questioner but perhaps interesting for researchers:

**NShape**

> [NShape](https://github.com/dataweb-GmbH/NShape/) is an Open Source diagram designing framework for .NET
>   WinForms. Software developers use NShape to integrate diagramming
>   capabilities into their applications. Using NShape, applications let
>   users view, annotate, modify and create diagrams like flow charts,
>   wiring schemes or project charts. NShape is open source and has a dual
>   license which allows it to be employed for free in open source
>   projects and for a license fee in commercial projects.

Answer (score 10):

Did you try the CodeProject article series by Sukram:

[*WPF Diagram Designer*](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/MemberArticles.aspx?amid=65924)

Comment: WPF is not Windows Form

Comment: True, but the original poster said "I can probably use 3.5 SP1 and WPF if there any suggestions in that arena."

Answer (score 6):

Here is some references which might be interesting for you:

**Diagram.NET**

> [Diagram.NET](http://www.dalssoft.com/diagram/) is a free open-source
> diagramming tools written entirely in
> C#.
> Put Diagram.NET WinForm Control into your form and, like Microsoft Visio®, the user can draw shapes and links. With some code you can control, change, add and delete these elements.

**Microsoft Chart Controls**

> [The samples environment for Microsoft
> Chart Controls for .NET Framework](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart)
> contains over 200 samples for both
> ASP.NET and **Windows Forms**. The
> samples cover every major feature in
> Chart Controls for .NET Framework.
> They enable you to see the Chart
> controls in action as well as use the
> code as templates for your own web and
> windows applications.

Answer (score 3):

**OpenDiagram**

> [Open Diagram](https://opendiagram.codeplex.com/) is the definitive open source .net diagramming
> component library for the .Net framework winforms environment.
>
> Use Open Diagram to add interactive data visualizations to your .net
> applications.

I have tried it with WinForms, works very well.

Answer (score 3):

I have similar request as yours. Here's one open source solution for drawing diagrams. It's from Microsoft and samples written in C#.

https://github.com/Microsoft/automatic-graph-layout

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that renders to **HTML5** (You can easily extend to Visio) from GridWizard/Github
**Source code:** https://github.com/gridwizard/SimpleFlowDiagram
**Wordpress doc:** https://gridwizard.wordpress.com/2015/03/25/simple-c-library-to-render-graph-to-flowchart/

Downside is, you need a viewer to display HTML5. Alternatively, SimpleFlowDiagramLib **already calculate Node.x and Node.y** - you can render it to Winform/WPF yourself (but then you need to code rendering yourself)

Answer (score -2):

Vote for NShape.  More or less it's fine.