# Cross-platform Diagram Editing Control for C#

Tags: c#, gtk#

I'm looking for a way to (in runtime) edit diagrams in a format much like UML. The catch being that I'd like to find a solution that works on all platforms. A GTK# control would fit that bill pretty well, while Winforms is a bit harder to work with. WPF is totally out of the picture.

[A related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005274/free-or-open-source-diagramming-component-for-winforms)

A lot of solutions listed before seem to be woefully out of date. Any suggestions or recommendations that I perhaps missed? Also accepted are any answers that provide a 'starting point' for just rolling my own. I'm not incredibly familiar with GTK#.

Comment: [yFiles](http://yworks.com) should work even on Mono (at least the WinForms variant).

Answer (score -1):

The problem with that libraries is that they are based on WinForms, and that's an unstable firm.

Gtk# includes [Cairo](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cairo/). Though I'm aware of it being a lot of work, you can easily draw in Cairo basic shapes like rectangles, lines...

Hope this helps.